# Updating column currentdate with today's date

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am updating two columns i.e visastatus and current date. When I update only my visastatus column then it is working fine but when I apply this query where both of the columns are updating then it is making my visastatus 0 and current date is also not updating. Is there any problem in my query?

```
    <?php  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   echo $radio = $_POST['radio'];
   $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d');
   $sql = "UPDATE user SET visastatus='$radio' and 
   currentdate='$date_clicked' WHERE id='$id'";  //this my update query.
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($query)
    {
        echo "<h4 style='color:green'>Action Performed Successfully....
  </h4>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h4 style='color:red'>Failed.</h4>";
    }
    }
    ?>
   <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 
    8px;" align="left">
      <label class="checkbox-inline tourist-rad">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="success" value="Successfull 
    done">Successfull
      </label>            
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label class="checkbox-inline tourist-rad">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="decline" value="Visa 
    declined">Declined
      </label>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit"  name="submit"  value="submit" class="btn 
    btn-primary" style="float: right;">Update Menu Item</button>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @AnkitKumar which is why we prefer hard facts to beliefs

Comment: Firstly you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for DB Connection.

Comment: This query is not working. @AnkitKumar

Comment: I have already included my connection file. My values are not updating in my table. @NiravMadariya

Comment: not talking about connection file, I'm saying you should use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of **mysqli_\*** functions, kindly refer to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE user SET visastatus=$radio,currentdate=$date_clicked WHERE id=$id
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for SQL update query is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

use `,` in place of `AND` in the query

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET visastatus='$radio', currentdate='$date_clicked' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Consider accepting the answer. Cheers.!